# Eclipse for Android programming

Tags: android

I'm looking for best option of eclipse to make android apps.
I had Juno Version, but I've lost it. 
What version should I use now? Please give me a link, there's so many options that I feel a bit confused.

Comment: I'd suggest the version that comes with the sdk in the ADT.

Comment: Just use the current version of Eclipse. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why worry about the Eclipse version. Download the latest ADT(Android Developer Tools) Bundle. Here is the link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. You also have option to use the existing IDE(info in same link). And just you know for questions like these you should first Google rather than asking here on SO.